# Replacing an entire column with an array - SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

Is it possible to replace a column with an array?

I have a column from 1....24 and I want to replace it with an array that has 24 distinct elements in it.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to transpose the table.

```
data have;
do i=1 to 24;
  output;
end;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want;
run;
```

Check out the documentation on `PROC TRANSPOSE` for more information and options.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1xno5xgs39b70n0zydov0owajj8.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other ways beyond `proc transpose`; I would suggest that for *most* use cases, but there are other cases where it's appropriate to do one of these.

The simplest way is to load it into the array using the `set` statement.  This is a common way to set up a `temporary` array that is used in very similar fashion to a hash table - prior to hash tables being in base SAS, in fact, this was how a lot of that work was done.

Note below the use of `do while` even though I'm searching for a `not` condition; you cannot use `do until` here due to the timing of that statement (try it and see if you can figure out why).

```
data want;
  array ages[19] _temporary_;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 while (not eof);  *iterate over `class` and load the array;
    set sashelp.class(keep=age) end=eof;
    ages[_n_] = age;
  end;
  call missing(age);       *not really needed;

  call sortn(of ages[*]);  *sort ascending;

  set sashelp.class;       *now the data step loop pulls one record at a time;
  age_rank = whichn(age, of ages[*]);  *calculates the rank of age;
run;
```

Of course don't use `_temporary_` if you want to store the variables from that array in the dataset.  And remember that `array` is a one-data-step construct, it *never* persists; you'd have to redeclare the array each data step you want to use it in, but the variables would already exist obviously.

Finally, if you want fewer rows, `output` selectively (after reaching the boundary condition) would be used to output only one row per [whatever].

There are other options; you could even load it into a hash table and then unload it into an array, if you had a reason to do that (I can't think of one, but who knows).

Comment: Hey Joe, can I do an inner join?

Comment: Doing this in SQL would be horrifically painful. SQL without pivot or similar (not supported in SAS) doesn't do transposes well.

Comment: Since you know the code that I'm using, what's the best way to do this if not an inner join? I need to modify a table, not a data step.  Can I just a column to the table and load the array into it and then drop the 1-24 column?